# C++: Using default printer without DoModal, but not able to change orientation on printout

Tags: c++, mfc

The setup is Windows 10 PC, Visual Studio 2017 programming in C++ (MFC).
The program does the following:
When HW trigger comes it among other things needs to print out a page. The printing of the page goes fine. The issue is that I want to check the orientation of the page, if it is set to portrait, then I want to set it to landscape.

```
CPrintDialog PrnDlg(FALSE);

if (PrnDlg.GetDefaults())
{
    DEV_MODE *pDevMode;

    pDevMode = (DEVMODE *)::GlobalLock(PrnDlg.m_pd.hDevMode);
    if (pDevMode->dmOrientation != DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        pDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
    }
    ::GlobalUnlock(PrnDlg.m_pd.hDevMode);
// More code here, but now shown

}
```

The problem is that the default printer still prints out in Portrait mode and not in Landscape mode.

If I instead of `PrnDlg.GetDefaults()` use `PrnDlg.DoModal()` functionality, then it works. So what am I missing?

Added more code to show the print part also. The code below is printing out to default printer. I did not add all the different code that I tried doing to set the page orientation.

```
    DOCINFO DocInfo;    
    CPrintInfo PrintInfo;     
    PRINTDLG pd;
    delete PrintInfo.m_pPD;
 
    // Next construct my CLPrintDlg instance and place the pointer in  
    CPrintInfo    PrintInfo.m_pPD = new CLPrintDlg(this,
       snPageSetupPaperOrientation,
       snPageSetupPaperSize,
       snPageSetupPaperSource);
 
    PrintInfo.m_bDocObject = FALSE;    
    PrintInfo.m_dwFlags = 0;
    PrintInfo.m_bDirect = FALSE;    
    PrintInfo.m_bPreview = FALSE;
 
    CPrintDialog PrnDlg(FALSE);    
    if (PrnDlg.GetDefaults())
    {
       CString StrTitle = _T("HISTOGRAM PRINTOUT");
 
       memset(&DocInfo, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO));
       DocInfo.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
       DocInfo.lpszDocName = StrTitle;
       DocInfo.lpszOutput = NULL;
 
       CDC dcPrint;
 
       dcPrint.Attach(PrnDlg.m_pd.hDC);
       dcPrint.m_bPrinting = TRUE;
       dcPrint.StartDoc(&DocInfo);
 
       int nYRes = dcPrint.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES);
       int nXRes = dcPrint.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES);
 
       dcPrint.SetMapMode(MM_HIMETRIC);
 
       CSize size;
       size.cx = nPageSetupLeftMargin;
       size.cy = nPageSetupTopMargin;
       dcPrint.HIMETRICtoDP(&size);
       int nLeftMarg = size.cx;
       int nTopMarg = size.cy;
 
       size.cx = nPageSetupRightMargin;
       size.cy = nPageSetupBottomMargin;
       dcPrint.HIMETRICtoDP(&size);
       int nRightMarg = size.cx;
       int nBottomMarg = size.cy;
 
       int nXAvailable = nXRes - nLeftMarg - nRightMarg;
       int nYAvailable = nYRes - nTopMarg - nBottomMarg;
 
       dcPrint.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
 
       dcPrint.StartPage();
 
       int nHeaderHeight = (int)(nYAvailable * HEADER_HEIGHT);
       int nMargBetweenHeaderAndHistogram = (int)(nYAvailable * 
                                      MARG_BETWEEN_HEADER_AND_HISTOGRAM);
       int nHistogramHeight = (int)(nYAvailable * HISTOGRAM_HEIGHT);
       int nMargBetweenHistogramAndLineReel = (int)(nYAvailable * 
                                      MARG_BETWEEN_HISTOGRAM_AND_LINE_REEL);
       int nLineReelHeight = (int)(nYAvailable * LINE_REEL_HEIGHT);
       int nMargBetweenLineReelAndData = (int)(nYAvailable * 
                                           MARG_BETWEEN_LINE_REEL_AND_DATA);
       int nDataHeight = (int)(nYAvailable * DATA_HEIGHT);
       int nMargBetweenDataAndFooter = (int)(nYAvailable * 
                                             MARG_BETWEEN_DATA_AND_FOOTER);
       int nFooterHeight = (int)(nYAvailable * FOOTER_HEIGHT);
       int nYOffset = nTopMarg;
 
       dcPrint.SetWindowExt(nXAvailable, nHeaderHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportExt(nXAvailable, nHeaderHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportOrg(nLeftMarg, nYOffset);
       pReelHeaderWnd->Print(dcPrint);
 
       nYOffset += nHeaderHeight + nMargBetweenHeaderAndHistogram;
       dcPrint.SetWindowExt(nXAvailable, nHistogramHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportExt(nXAvailable, nHistogramHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportOrg(nLeftMarg, nYOffset);
       pReelViewWnd->ShowPileWidthButtons(false);
       pReelViewWnd->Print(dcPrint);      
       pReelViewWnd->ShowPileWidthButtons(true);
 
       nYOffset += nHistogramHeight + nMargBetweenHistogramAndLineReel;
       dcPrint.SetWindowExt(nXAvailable, nLineReelHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportExt(nXAvailable, nLineReelHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportOrg(nLeftMarg, nYOffset);
       pLineReelInfoWnd->Print(szLineName, szReelId, dcPrint);
 
       nYOffset += nLineReelHeight + nMargBetweenLineReelAndData;
       dcPrint.SetWindowExt(nXAvailable, nDataHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportExt(nXAvailable, nDataHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportOrg(nLeftMarg, nYOffset);
       CRect rect(0, 0, nXAvailable, nDataHeight);
       //dcPrint.Rectangle( rect ); // Debug
       pReelDataWnd->Print(dcPrint);
 
       nYOffset += nDataHeight + nMargBetweenDataAndFooter;
       dcPrint.SetWindowExt(nXAvailable, nFooterHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportExt(nXAvailable, nFooterHeight);
       dcPrint.SetViewportOrg(nLeftMarg, nYOffset);
       //dcPrint.Rectangle( 0,0, nXAvailable, nFooterHeight ); // Debug
       pReelFooterWnd->Print(CLConfig::szCompanyName, dcPrint);
 
       dcPrint.EndPage();
       dcPrint.EndDoc();
    }
```

Comment: You don't actually show us how you print . The `CWinAppEx` class have two built-in member variables: `m_hDevMode` and  `m_hDevNames`.  In my application I restore printer settings to / from these structures. So I think you need to feed your changes into these structures.

Comment: Hi Andrew Truckle, many thanks for your answer. And yes I did not show the rest of my code, as I thought the setup related to the PrnDlg part only. I use CDC dcPrint, where I do things like margin setup and make a graphical object and then print(dcPrint). The code I work on uses CWinApp and not CWinAppEx. I will look into this some more.

Comment: Please post your code without all the leading `>` characters.

Comment: Adrian Mole edit the code so that > is now not present.

Answer (score 1):

Code adapted from the old KB article Q126897 "How to Change Default
Printer Settings in an MFC Application".

```
void CMyApp::SetPrinterOrientation(bool bLandScape /*= false*/)
{
    // Get default printer settings.
    PRINTDLG   pd;

    pd.lStructSize = (DWORD)sizeof(PRINTDLG);
    if (GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&pd))
    {
        // Lock memory handle.
        DEVMODE * pDevMode = (DEVMODE FAR*)::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode);
        LPDEVNAMES lpDevNames;
        LPTSTR lpszDriverName, lpszDeviceName, lpszPortName;
        HANDLE hPrinter;

        if (pDevMode)
        {
            // Change printer settings in here.
            pDevMode->dmOrientation =  bLandScape? DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE : DMORIENT_PORTRAIT;
            // Unlock memory handle.
            lpDevNames = (LPDEVNAMES)GlobalLock(pd.hDevNames);
            lpszDriverName = (LPTSTR)lpDevNames + lpDevNames->wDriverOffset;
            lpszDeviceName = (LPTSTR)lpDevNames + lpDevNames->wDeviceOffset;
            lpszPortName = (LPTSTR)lpDevNames + lpDevNames->wOutputOffset;

            ::OpenPrinter(lpszDeviceName, &hPrinter, NULL);
            ::DocumentProperties(NULL, hPrinter, lpszDeviceName, pDevMode,  pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER);

            // Sync the pDevMode.
            // See SDK help for DocumentProperties for more info.
            ::ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevNames);
            ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, using the two variables I referred to in my comment.

Comment: Hi Tom Tom, many thanks for your answer. I will add the code below.